# Django 1.9 InlineAdmin displaying duplicate fields in custom user profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am fairly new to Django. Using Django 1.9 i created a custom user model and extended it with Profile model by sub-classing custom user model.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False, help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=USERS_AUTO_ACTIVATE,
                help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(_('mobile phone'), max_length=15, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserInheritanceManager()
    base_objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')

class Profile(User, TimeStampedModel):
    gender_choices = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=1, choices=gender_choices, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(_('profile image'), upload_to=create_image_path, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User Profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users Profile')
```

Here are the code snippet from my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages 
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .models import Profile as UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileAdmin, ]
User = get_user_model()
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

When i try to edit a user in django admin it displays the User Model fields like password, username, email etc in UserProfile screen as well i.e twice. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Isn't these fields should be displayed once only. Any help is appreciated.